# Como puedo recorrrer una condicionante con laravel blade

Tags: laravel

Hola muy buenas tardes... Estoy haciendo un sistema de encuestas y entre en la parte en donde tengo que mostrar los resultados de la encuesta...

Tengo una tabla de respuestas en donde hay 10 columnas con el nombre respuesta1, respuesta2, respuesta3,.... hasta, respuesta10. Lo que hago es recorrer las columnas que tienen registro y contarlas para saber cuantas respuesta tuvo una pregunta y aqui esta el problema.

```
    @foreach($votos as $voto)
    @if($voto->idpregunta == $pregunta_id)
        @if(Auth::user()->id == $voto->user_id)
            <?php $habilitado = "no" ?>
        @endif
        @if(!empty($voto->respuesta1))
            <?php $count+=1; $texto="$voto->respuesta1";?>
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Como se ve en el codigo si quiero hacer para las 10 respuestas tengo que hacer 10 if para contarlas, asi como 10 variables donde guardarlas y va a quedar muy feo el codigo.. **de por si ya esta feo**..

Mi pregunta es.. como puedo hacer un recorrido de forma en que no tenga que hacer 10 veces la condicionante. Lo que necesito es un poco de ayuda para poder arrancar...

En mi controlador no hay mucho que mostrar pues solo envio datos...

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $preguntas = Pregunta::all();
    $votos = Respuesta::all();
    $respuesta = new Respuesta;
    return view('user.respuesta.respuesta', compact('preguntas', 'respuesta', 'votos'));
}
```

Cualquier ayuda les agradezco.. quisiera poder hacer el codigo anterior en el controlador pero no se muy bien como hacerlo pues soy un novato

Comment: Donde estan las relaciones?

Comment: para que las relaciones.. los tengo directamente en el dump, esta relacionado el id de la pregunta con la respuesta, en eso no tengo problema

Comment: Por que las relaciones son esenciales en este asunto, se puede hacer de mil maneras pero tal como lo tienes planteado es una mala practica y luego vienen problemas como este. Si tuvieras bien planteado los modelos con sus relaciones podrías hacer una sola consulta que te devuelva las preguntas con sus respuestas contestadas y contadas y no tendrias que hacer ningun if en una vista que tb es una mala practica ya q las vistas son para mostrar datos no para la logica.